# Spring Data Rest item vs association links?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

If I have a spring data rest parent child one-to-one relationship, The link to self when doing a get on the child is

```
...../rest/child/12
```

And a get on parent has the following:
child: {

```
href: "...../rest/parent/1/child"
```

And it turns out, these 2 links point to the same resource, but I believe if I understand it one is pointing to the item resource and the other is pointing to the association resource. Is there a way to have the get on the parent return the child item resource link instead of this association link? I think something I'm confused on in general is if HAL treats URIs as IDs why these two disparate links point to the same thing.